# Paste value using multiple loops

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset where `range("B1:L1")` contains dates and `range("A2:A10")` contains names.

`Range("O5")` contain the `concern date` and `range("O6")` contain the `concern name`.

I want to search `range("O5")` date in `range("B1:L1")` and `range("O6")`name in `range("A2:A10")` and if criterias met then enter text `"done"` in the concern cell only.

For example if the `concern date` is in `D1` and concern name is in `A6` then text should be pasted in `D6`.

Can someone please help me with the code?

---

**Code**

---

```
Sub Status()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    For Each cel In Range("B1:L1")
        For Each zzz In Range("A2:A10")
            If cel.Value = Range("O5").Value And zzz.Value = Range("O6").Value Then
                Range(cel, zzz).Select
                Selection = "Done"
            End If
        Next zzz
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your latest code attempt. Also, you have not found the time to credit any of answers you got here to your previous posts here. I'm sure you can find the time to give credit to people that spent time to answer your questions.

Comment: Echoing the previous comment, please see [Why is "Can someone help me" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Oooooo This is fun. So there are tons of different ways to approach your issue. Since you're looking for code, ill explain what you need to teach yourself to get there: 1.Looping through Ranges 2. Referring to cell value that corresponds to the current position of the loop. 3.Setting a cell value in a worksheet. 4. Bonus points if you "Store range in an array" and process it that way. I have provided you with enough stuff that you should be able to google yourself into something that works easily.

Comment: Above is the code that I have written. However, when I run the code, it will paste the text "done" in the entire range. I want to paste the value only on the concern cell. it would be great if you could kindly solve it.